# Dictionary change without change in code

Tags: python

Here is my problem, I use a dictionary but I want to get a copy of it before I change it. Like this I can compare both dictionary to now if they are difference.

I do it like this:

```
old_dic = dict(data)
```

but after I change the data with a function and it's done like this

```
data = play_turn(data)
```

But after that I want to print the `old_dic` but it also changed. Of course I didn't change it in the function `play_turn` and I tried to only change data and then print both but only data changed. 
play_turn makes many change in the data. The play_turn function make the ship (key in the dictionary because it is a game) change direction or change speed but every information is stocked in the data dictionary.
In the dictionary there is also dictionary for some key or some list also.

How can I not change the `old_dic` during the `play_turn` function?

Comment: Please give a [mcve]  - what does `play_turn` do?

Comment: It makes many change in the data. The play_turn function make the ship (key in the dictionary because it is a game) change direction or change speed but every information is stocked in the data dictionary

Comment: Don't *describe* it, [edit] the question to provide a MCVE as I asked above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to **clone** the dictionary like this

```
import copy
old_dic_copy = copy.deepcopy(data)
```

you need use `=` when you want to copy the **reference** to the object

use `.copy` or `.deepcopy` when you want to clone the object

then you can print him after change the new one :)

Comment: I've tried but didn't word

Comment: `deepcopy` will be necessary if there's multiple levels of dictionaries or other lists inside the dictionary, so try that

Comment: look at the answer again.. you need to import copy

Comment: Thank you I found the answer. A really BIG thanks